# message body is blank while sending mail through php for hotmail

Tags: php

The mail is coming nice for all accounts except for the hotmail.
in hotmail the message body is getting blank.but while checking with view sources the message body is displaying.please help us
is there any setting need to change for hotmail

```
function Trigger_WelcomeEmail(&$tNG) {

global $DID;

$emailObj = new tNG_Email($tNG);
$emailObj->setFrom("test <test@test.com>");
$emailObj->setTo("{email}");
$emailObj->setCC("");
$emailObj->setBCC("test@test.com");
$emailObj->setSubject("Smile! You Were Successfully Registered for test.com");




$emailObj->setContentFile("welcomeUS.html");


$emailObj->setEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
$emailObj->setFormat("HTML/Text");
$emailObj->setImportance("Normal");
return $emailObj->Execute();
}
```

Comment: They might be blocking your HTML

Answer (score 1):

Usually a header is set to Content-type:text/html

Perhaps it is reading your one wrong because your code; $emailObj->setFormat("HTML/Text"); has that backwards. Probably just a shot in the dark, but worth a shot!

Comment: actually i placed there format not content type
predefaulty its taking content-type:Text/plain

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure you aren't sending two newline characters in a row in the welcomeUS.html file. This will close the body of the email and the remainder of the text might be ignored.

Some email service providers might ignore that issue automatically when they see more content being delivered after the newlines, but hotmail may not.